# notifyDataSetChanged not working in android

Tags: android

The list view is not updating data when the notifyDataChanged() method called.

In onCreate() method i initialized the the listview with no data.

```
            ListView videoList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.videos_list);
    videoList.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    listAdapter = new PHVideosListAdapter(PHVideosActivity.this, videos);
    videoList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

After this I started fetching list of video using new VideosCategoryFetchTask().execute();

in the post execute method I called

```
            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        if(success) {
             listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            //show dialog
        }
    }
```

but nothing is displayed on the list. If anybody knew the solution please help...

```
 private class VideosDetailsFetchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Boolean success = false;
        try {
            if (params.length >= 0) {
                videos = (Videos)videoAPI.videosForCategoryId(params[0],new VideosParser());
                success = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return success;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {

        if(success) {
              progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              onFinishVideoFetch();
        } else {
            //show dialog   
        }       
    }
}
```

here  using two Async classes sec one is called on the onPostExecute() of first one..

```
   private void onFinishVideoFetch() {
    if(videos != null) {

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I 'm not fetching videos one by one.. here a list of videos is returned....

After getting the list of videos i wanted to refresh the list.

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Videos... values) {

    videos = values[0];
 //add published object to list which holds
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

I tried this but no luck please help..

this is the adapter class used

public class PHVideosListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
private Videos videoTitles;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public PHVideosListAdapter(Context context, Videos videoTitles) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.videoTitles = videoTitles;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(videoTitles != null) {
        return videoTitles.size();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return videoTitles.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    VideoListViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new VideoListViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos_list, null);
            holder.videoTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            holder.videoImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_image);
            holder.videoDuration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_duration);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (VideoListViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.videoImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    holder.videoDuration.setText("00:10");
    holder.videoTitle.setText(videoTitles.get(position).getVideoTitle());
    return convertView;
}


   private class VideoListViewHolder {

     ImageView videoImage;
     TextView  videoTitle;
     TextView  videoDuration;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you paste your whole `VideosCategoryFetchTask` class?

Comment: Just to check: if you step through your code in debug mode, are you sure `notifyDataSetChanged()` is actually being called? Just to rule out that there is a bug somewhere else.

Comment: The code for PHVideosListAdapter would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

When you first create your `PHVideosListAdapter`, it is holding a reference to the `Videos` list that I assume is a member of your Activity.  In your `doInBackground` method, the call to `videoAPI.videosForCategoryId` is updating the `Videos` reference in your Activity, but the adapter is still holding the original reference that was passed in to the constructor for `PHVideosListAdapter`.  You need to either recreate the `PHVideosListAdapter` in `onPostExecute` or add a set method in `PHVideosListAdapter` to change the private variable `videoTitles`.

I ran into the same issue with using the `ArrayAdapter` provided by Google.  You can only set the underlying `List` in the constructor, so you must recreate the ArrayAdapter or create your own class that allows changing of the underlying data for `notifyDataSetChanged` to work.

Comment: create a set method which update the private variable. This is the best way

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onProgressUpdate()` of AsynTask class

Heres an example of AsyncTask assuming your list is `videos` which holds Objects of type `Video` and your extended adapter is `VideosAdapter`

```
private class VideosDetailsFetchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Video, Boolean> {    
    @Override    
    public void onPreExecute() {    
        super.onPreExecute();    
    }    

    @Override    
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {    
    //utilize string you are passing otherwise use Void as first generic param.        
    Boolean success = false;    
        try {    
            if (params.length >= 0) {    
                Videos videoFetched = (Videos)PrimeraHoraAPI.videosForCategoryId(params[0],new VideosParser());    
                success = true;
                publishProgress(videoFetched);
            }    
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            // TODO: handle exception    
        }    
        return success;    
    }    

    @Override    
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {    

        if(success) {    
              progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
              onFinishVideoFetch();    
        } else {    
            //show dialog       
        }           
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Video... values) {
        videos.add(values[0]);//add published object to list which holds
        ((VideosAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very good descript anywhere but what you do when u call

`listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

u tell your machine "oke, your code is not legit" and now u stop! so basically ur machine has no clue what 2 do next! My solution is:

create a private void setupData()

```
private void setupData() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        final List<Table_Follow> data = db.getAllData(); // from database
        HashMap<String,String> item;
        for(Table_Data td : data){
            item = new HashMap<String,String>();
            item.put("name1", td.getName_One());
            item.put("name2", td.getName_Two());
            item.put("date", td.getDate());
            list.add(item);
        };

        my_data = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.my_listview_row, new String[] { "name1","name2", "date" }, new int[] {R.id.lv_line_a, R.id.lv_line_b, R.id.lv_line_c});
        listview.setAdapter(my_data);
    }
```

I have a custom layout with 3 textviews (line a > title, line b > subtitle, line c > time see bottom page for xml). So basicly i ll use this private void to tell my machine what 2 do next by using setupData() after calling > notifydatasetchanged() in my main thread

```
my_data.notifyDataSetChanged();
setupData();
```

One last thing! I use the android listview id for my listview in my main xml file! Oh and if you have trouble using your 'onItemClickListener' (not giving u the right id, just text me! I faced that problem and solved it pretty shitty but it works :p)

My xml file for my listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lv_line_c"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lv_line_a"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lv_line_b"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```