# Want to update or refresh listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have listview which is looking like below

[image]

it is one kind of Radio based application

in that when user tap on image AsyncTask will be called and Music will be played and getting some information
which will be replaced with AMIT SIDDHPURA text

below is my code

```
    holder.imgPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    new MetadataTask2().execute(holder.txtMetadata);



                            }

    class StreamHolder {
        TextView txtStreamName;
        TextView txtStream;
        TextView txtMetadata;
        ImageView imgPlay;
    }
```

And MetaDataTask2 class code is below

```
   class MetadataTask2 extends AsyncTask<TextView, Void, IcyStreamMeta> {
    String title_artist;
    TextView txtView;

    @Override
    protected com.example.xmlparsingex.IcyStreamMeta doInBackground(TextView... arg0) {
        txtView = arg0[0];

        return streamMeta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(IcyStreamMeta result) {
        try {
            txtView.setText("Hiiiiiiiiiii............");
            MCObjectMetadata.cancel();
            MCObjectMetadata = new MyCounterMetadata(10000, 1000);
            MCObjectMetadata.start();

            **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mainListView.invalidate();**

            startService(new Intent(CompaniesList.this, NotifyService.class));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        try {
            PD = ProgressDialog.show(CompaniesList.this, "Tuning...", "Please Wait...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but the problem is that listview is not updating means the orange text which is displaying in listview is not replacing with **Hiiiiiii**

Answer (score 0):

If its a ListView I would prefer to change the textview in the Adapter's getView() method...or if list is cursor backed then in bindView().....i am not sure about your method though.

Comment: it is an arrayadapter and it can't be with getView because we have to first call AsyncTask method and after getting information from net i have to update list view so it is not being done

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to recreate your adapter instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. See [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092342/475217) for an explanation.